# Nested axios requests from different web services

Tags: node.js, express, asynchronous, request, axios

I have a problem (using NodeJS + Express) trying to retrieve in **'users'** information from 3 different requests (2 domains) and I can't get what I want. I'd like a function **getAllUsers()** to return something like this:

```
[
    {
        "username": "joe_example",
        "plays": 178,
        "friends": 7,
        "uri": "/users/joe_example"
    },
    ...snip additional users...
]
```

Here's my main function:

```
async function getAllUsers() {
    let users = await axios.get('http://localhost:8000/friends')
        .then(response => { 
            response.data["friends"].map(user => {
                user = getUser(user.username)
            })
        })
        .catch(error => console.log(error))
    return users 
}

async function getUser(name) {
    let user = await axios.all(
        [
            axios.get('http://localhost:8000/friends/' + name),
            axios.get('http://localhost:8001/plays/' + name)
        ]).then(axios.spread((res1, res2) => {
            user["username"] = name
            user["friends"] = res1.data["friends"].length
            user["plays"] = res2.data["plays"].length
            user["uri"] = "/users/" + name
        })).catch(error => { console.log(error) })
    return user 
}
```

Yes, it may sounds crazy...Friends service has user names and you have to call `/friends/<username>` in order to retrieve the amount of friends each user has, same with `/plays/<username>`

Any ideas or suggestions ? I've tried all I know :(

Comment: Do you have a problem with both function?

Comment: `getUser(user.username)` is into `getAllUsers()` to make code more modular but yeah, it's a problem with both. I don't know yet how to retrieve properly the data. It returns nothing yet but the calls are allright, verified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works charmly, here is the right solution, nice help using **Promise.all**. I didn't know how useful is. I made some minors changes too:

```
async function getUser(username) {
    let user = {}
    await axios.all(
        [
            axios.get('http://localhost:8000/friends/' + username),
            axios.get('http://localhost:8001/plays/' + username)
        ]).then(axios.spread((res1, res2) => {
            user["username"] = username
            user["friends"] = res1.data["friends"].length
            user["plays"] = res2.data["plays"].length
            user["uri"] = "/users/" + username
        })).catch(error => { console.log(error) })
    return user
}

async function getAllUsers() {
    let users = []
    try{
        const { data } = await axios.get('http://localhost:8000/friends')
        const friends = data["friends"].map(user => getUser(user.username))
        users = await Promise.all(friends)
    } catch(error) { console.log(error) }
    return users
}
```

Thanks everyone by your attention !!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your `getUser` works and `data["friends"]` is an array as you expect:

```
async function getAllUsers() {
  let users;
  try {
    const { data } = await axios.get('http://localhost:8000/friends')
    const friends = data["friends"].map(user => getUser(user.username))
    users = await Promise.all(friends)
  } catch(error) {
    console.log(error)
  }
  return users 
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Now I have an array of nulls as result but that's a good step I believe, I didn't know nothing about **Promise.all**. Now maybe something weird lefts with my helper getUser(user.username) function. Console says: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`